# How can I convert GTM-0006 to ISO without Adding hours

Tags: javascript, date, dom-events

I'm working in a from who has a date field and by default it shows the current date.

I set the date using this:

```
var date = new Date();  = Tue May 25 2021 17:06:01 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) {}**
```

Everything works fine, but when I send the data to the controller, the JSON automatically converts it to ISO and the date received by the controller is 6 hours  in advance.

I understand a little bit the context  about GMT-0006 (my current timezone is 6 hours more than the 0 timezone), and the fact that my controllers received the date in ISO format because when I converted to ISO format is the same problem

```
date.toISOString() = "2021-05-25T23:06:01.861Z"  (6 hours  in advance)
```

so my question is, there is a way to create a date that allows me to use `.toISOString()` and keep the same?
or  create a date with my current hour but -0000 so when I convert it to `toISOString` keeps the same?

Comment: What date do you get if you parse the generated ISO string, as in `new Date('2021-05-25T23:06:01.861Z')`? Is the date 6 hours ahead or is it the same exact time? The "Z" denotes utc/zero offset. It's the same time, just in a different zone. As long as you save the date as the ISO string, whatever consumes it will be able to parse it in the correct local time zone, similar to how you could do `new Date('2021-05-25T23:06:01.861Z')` and it's the **exact** same time as what you started with. Don't try to take off the "Z" or change the hours, it's in a format that will work on different clients.

Comment: An additional question. Given an event such as birthday happens on that exact moment of your new Date() and you are putting this on a calendar in web app. What would you expect for the Chicago user to see in their calendar for a Mountain event?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky—if you have another question, post a new question. Dates without time do not have a timezone, 1 Jan starts on 1 Jan locally. If you are just west of the international date line at say 01:00 on your birthday, going east over the line means it's now the day before and no longer your birthday, you have to wait for the new day… :-)

Comment: @RobG i hear what you are saying but I didn’t create this question, I was asking clarifying questions to the OP to understand the issue and expectations. There Date object has date and time, I wasn’t implying just a date without a time.